# Tweet with Twitter API "statuses/update" endpoint - text with brackets causes error

Tags: api, twitter, endpoint, brackets

I use Twitter API v1.1 to do tweets with my application. All is working good, while I don't try to post text with "()" - in this case I got error:

```
"Error [32]: Could not authenticate you."
```

Does anyone know, how to screen brackets, and what is the full list of prohibited symbols for Twitter API "statuses/update endpoint?

Comment: What coding language are you using? Can you share code? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What encoding are you using? Brackets can definitely be included in Tweets.

Comment: Coding language is C#. I use Twity plugin for Unity3d. I didn't realise it could be on the plugin side as well. Will investigate this way too, thank you.